# Limpar campo após X tempo

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tenho o formulário abaixo, que após 2 minutos ele atualiza toda página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o comando abaixo:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="120;URL=http://pcn-sig.peccin.local/cracha">
```

E com esse ele reseta o formulário em cada acesso:

```
<body class="noheader" onload="moveRelogio(); getInfo(); document.cadastro.reset()">
```

Mas estou tendo um problema, pois as maquinas cedidas para essa aplicação são bem lentas, K6 2 500 para baixo, e em algumas a página demora de 5 a 10 segundos para abrir, sendo que aqui onde testei não demora 1 segundo. Como poderia fazer para "limpar" somente o campo crachá ao invés de toda página?

Trecho do formulário:

```html
          <form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="POST" action="adicionaBatida.php" autocomplete="off">
            <table cellspacing="0">

              <tr>
                  <td>Data:</td>
                  <td><input type = "text" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; height: 40px; font-size: 30px;" readonly="true" id="data_inicio" name = "data_inicio" size = 12 maxlength =10  value= "<? echo date('d-m-Y');?>" ></td>
              </tr>
              
              <tr>
                  <td>Hora Atual:</td>
                  <td><input type = "text" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; height: 40px; font-size: 30px;" readonly="true" id="hora_inicio" name = "hora_inicio" size = 12></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                 <td>Crachá: </td>
                 <td><input type = "password" name="cracha" id="cracha" placeholder="Passe o crachá..." size = 15 maxlength = 10 onChange="getDados();" onkeyup="troca_campo(this)"  onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" autofocus></td>
              </tr>


              <? // EXIBE O NOME ?>
              <tr>
                 <td></td>
                 <td><textarea cols="25" rows="10" wrap="hard" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; height: 80px; font-size: 30px;" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Aguardando crachá..." size="35" readonly="true"></textarea></td>
               </tr>
```

Comment: Deverá limpar o campo independente se tiver algo nele ou não?

Comment: Olá Diego, poste o código do seu formulário

Comment: @Randrade, sim, pois algum engraçadinho pode digitar no teclado númerico e sair, ou passar o crachá sem confirmar, ai o campo fica preenchido e a pessoa seguinte não tem como passar. Thomas Lima vou editar a pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function LimpaCracha(){
    document.getElementById('cracha').value = '';
}

setInterval(function(){
    LimpaCracha();
}, 10 * 1000);
```

> onde 10 é o número de segundos.

Limpa a cada 10 segundos.

Comment: Estava fazendo o fiddle enquanto respondeu. Então vou deixar apenas sua resposta e postar [o fiddle aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/q1ayj63y/4/).

Comment: Exatamente! Mas notei que ele executa somente uma vez. Tem como ficar "constante" a chamada a função?

Comment: @Diego Olhe o exemplo que adicionei. É quase o mesmo código que o que ele postou.

Comment: Isso @Diego. Use o script do Randrade.

Comment: Obrigado @Zoom e Randrade, deu certo. Era exatamente isso que precisava.

Comment: Metade dos pontos deveriam ser para o @Randrade.